# jQuery/JS select only elements that directly contain text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to select all the `<a>` elements on the page with either jQuery or straight javascript. The catch is I only way to select it if the anchor directly contains text and nothing else. Is there a way to select only text nodes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

Comment: please explain more... give a simple example. I dont understand your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this: `$('a:not(:has(*))')`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QAamN/

Comment: Wait... it works, but I don't think I can use jQuery. I'm passing the selector through a function. so I have this:

linkify('a:not(:has(*))')

Comment: And linkify is a function elsewhere in my code. How can I get that to work?

Comment: @Jackson Gariety: Not sure what you mean, but if you have a function `linkify(myVariable){...}` you should be able to use `$(myVariable)` inside that function, as zolex suggested.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the jQuery filter method to achieve that

```
$("a").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
});
```